# Akra-Bazzi method - constructive proof

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

As I was familiarizing myself with different methods of computing complexities of recurrences, I stumbled upon the Akra-Bazzi method. Seeing such a beautiful result literally made my day.

I was able to come up with a proof that makes use of an inductive argument, but induction alone isn't all that satisfactory.

---

Does anyone know of a material that illustrates a constructive proof of this wonderful result?

---